# How to achieve the same functionality with (**) operator instead of pow

Tags: ruby, modulo

I am trying to participate in a coding [challenge](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/moving-d6f7a605/description/) where for the large numbers I need to take a modulo with (10 ^ 9 + 7). Since the website support only ruby 2.3.1 version so I can't make use of pow() [function](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Integer/pow). When I am trying to solve the same problem with (**) operator. It is giving me infinity. So, my questions are

1) What exactly is the difference between (**) and pow operator

2) I need a way to achieve the same functionality what pow operator provides

Below is the program

```
mod = ((10 ** 9) + 7)
q = gets.to_i
while q != 0 do
  n = gets.to_i
  if (n % 2 == 0 || n == 1)
    puts 0
  else
    val = (n - 3)/2
    puts 2.pow(val, mod)
    ### now If I do puts (2 ** ( val % mod)) it will give me infinite
  end
  q -= 1
end
```

input 
q = 3

n - will be a very large number such as 899187440761857221 or 889644209960741769

If I am running the program in my local machine I am able to run it because I am using ruby latest version whereas on the website they support 2.3.1 version

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is exactly what the docs you linked say, without a modulo parameter the result is the same as calling `base**exponent`, but with a modulo parameter it will calculate the result without overflowing the type, which can happen when doing direct modular exponentiation `(base ** exponent) % modulo` with large values for `base` and `exponent`.

Below is a ruby implementation of the modular exponentiation based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Memory-efficient_method

```
  def pow_with_modulus(base, exponent, modulus)
    return 0 if modulus == 1

    res = 1
    exponent.times do
      res = (res * base) % modulus
    end

    res
  end
```

You can see from the implementation that the intermediary value can never be greater than `modulus * base`, which keeps it below overflow. It will of course overflow if `base * modulus` overflows.

EDIT:
A more performant version, adapted from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method

```
  def pow_with_modulus(base, exponent, modulus)
    return 0 if modulus == 1

    res = 1
    base = base % modulus

    while exponent > 0
      res = (res * base) % modulus if exponent.odd?
      exponent = exponent >> 1
      base = (base * base) % modulus
    end

    res
  end
```

Comment: *So, my questions are: 1) What exactly is the difference between (\*\*) and pow operator*

Comment: @Boris When I am using your function it is taking ages to calculate the result. Whereas pow operator gives an immediate result

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari I updated the answer with an O(log exponent) version.

Comment: @BorisB. A great solution I wasn't aware of these ways of finding Modulo